# What will happen if object property is provided a value as "this"?

Tags: javascript, object

Here, the property "self" is given a value as "this". what will be output of the current scenario

```
var obj = {
   foo: "bar",
   self: this,
   myfunc: function() {
     console.log("1 " + obj.foo);
     console.log("2 " + self.foo);
     (function() {
        console.log("3 " + obj.foo);
        console.log("4 " + self.foo);
      })();
   }
};

obj.myfunc(); //invoking the object's function
```

Comment: `what will be output of the current scenario` - don't you know? is that your question? did you try?

Comment: I am not getting expected output, i was thinking of getting below mentioned output:
bar
bar
bar
bar
but getting different,so need some explanation about this.

Comment: `this` points to `Window` which does not have a property `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

`this` given as value to `self` in `obj` points to context of whoever creating obj. If you run directly it is `window` object.

`this` in below case used in `myFunc` points to context of `obj` object so you can get value of `this.foo` as "bar".

```js
// context: window
var obj = {
   foo: "bar",
   self: this,
   myfunc: function() { // context: obj
     console.log("1 " + this.foo);
     console.log("2 " + this.self.foo);
     (function() { // context: window
        console.log("3 " + this.obj.foo);
        console.log("4 " + this.self.foo);
      })();
   }
};

obj.myfunc(); //invoking the object's function
```